# Only run task if subelement is present

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a list of variables and I want my task to only run if something is present.

My variables:

```
var:
  user:
  - name: A
    group: A
    directory: A
  - name: B
    group: B
    directory: B
  - name: A
    group: A
```

And my task:

```
- name: create custom data directories
  file:
    state: directory
    path: "{{ item.0.username }}/data/{{ item.1 }}"
    mode: "0700"
    owner: "{{ item.0.username }}"
    group: "{{ item.0.group }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ var.user }}"
    - directory
```

Obviously my task should only create directories for user A and B, but not for C, so the task should only run if `directory` is present.

Adding a `when: var.user[item]['directory'] is present` does not work.

Comment: `when: var.user[item].directory is defined`. For Ansible, this is just an attribute of a dictionary, not a directory, at that point.

Comment: Does not work either. (And I am still confused what is a dictonary and what is a list)

Comment: Ho yes, `var.user[item]` is also wrong... `(var.user | selectattr('name', '==', item) | first).directory is defined`. For dictionaries and list: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: If you are looping on `var.user` (cf your edit), then it is even easier to do `when: item.0.directory is defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop, select only items where the attribute *directory* is defined

```yaml
      loop: "{{ user|selectattr('directory', 'defined') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    user:
      - {directory: A, group: A, name: A}
      - {directory: B, group: B, name: B}
      - {group: A, name: A}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          path: "{{ item.name }}/data/{{ item.directory }}"
          owner: "{{ item.name }}"
          group: "{{ item.group }}"
      loop: "{{ user|selectattr('directory', 'defined') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'directory': 'A', 'group': 'A', 'name': 'A'}) => 
  msg: |-
    path: "A/data/A"
    owner: "A"
    group: "A"
ok: [localhost] => (item={'directory': 'B', 'group': 'B', 'name': 'B'}) => 
  msg: |-
    path: "B/data/B"
    owner: "B"
    group: "B"

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 2):

You might benefit from refactoring your `users` list into a dictionary, for easier access.

With the structure

```yaml
users:
  A:
    group: A
    directory: A
  B:
    group: B
    directory: B
  C:
    group: A
```

You will be able direct access to elements in an easier fashion:

```yaml
{{ users.A.directory }} # yields A
{{ users.C.directory is defined }} # yields False
```

So, in the current use case, your condition become:

```yaml
when: var.users[item].directory is defined
```

---

If you have to loop on this `users` variables, you can still do it.
For example, those two tasks are equivalent.

With a list structure

```
- debug:
    msg: "User {{ item.name }} is in {{ item.group }}"
  loop: "{{ users }}" 
  vars:
    users:
      - name: A
        group: A
        directory: A
      - name: B
        group: B
```

With a dictionary structure

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "User {{ item.key }} is in {{ item.value.group }}"
  loop: "{{ users | dict2items }}" 
  vars:
    users:
      A:
        group: A
        directory: A
      B:
        group: B
```

But, as said before, the dictionary structure offers an easier direct access.